# NgWebDriver can't click on element after angular 6 version migrated

Tags: c#, angular, selenium, automation, protractor

Current configuration I am using:

> Chrome- 73
>   Protractor- 0.12.0
>   Nunit - 3.11.0
>   Chromedriver- 3.141.0
>   Windows- 10

After migration on Angular 6, my testing framework does't click on elements. I use NgWebDriver

Page

```
<div class="home-page--sections">
<!---->
<a id="menuItemImgBtnTransactions" class="home-page--section" href="/sales/transactions">
```

Code

```
 NgWebDriver driver;
 public HomePage(IWebDriver driver)
 {
    this.driver = (NgWebDriver)driver;
 }
```

```
 By transactionsTab = By.Id("menuItemImgBtnTransactions");


//driver.WaitForAngular(); // I use wait PageLoad,AsynchronousJavaScript waiters
IWebElement transaction = driver.FindElement(transactionsTab);
transaction.Click();
```

I use usual WD for landing (login) page, it works properly, but when I try to go to transaction page with ng driver (a lot of tests wrote with ngdriver = my framework)

I'm getting OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException
session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86 Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68()

Have any thoughts?

Comment: So you’re using NgWebdriver **and** Protractor? Why’s that? I think you should probably use just one of those two (and if it were me I would definitely pick Protractor).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
By transactionsTab = By.Id("menuItemImgBtnTransactions");


//driver.WaitForAngular(); // I use wait PageLoad,AsynchronousJavaScript waiters
driver.FindElement(transaction));
transaction.Click();
```

You’ve defined your locator as `transactionsTab`, but you’re passing `transaction` into the `FindElement()` function. Not sure why you’re defining the locator as a variable but the following should work if you use that strategy:

```
By transactionsTab = By.Id("menuItemImgBtnTransactions");


//driver.WaitForAngular(); // I use wait PageLoad,AsynchronousJavaScript waiters
driver.FindElement(transactionsTab)).Click();
```

You can also do it in one line:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id(“menuItemImgBtnTransactions”)).Click();
```

Or, if you want to reuse that WebElement I would do this:

```
IWebElement transactions = driver.FindElement(By.Id(“menuItemImgBtnTransactions));
transactions.Click();
```

The you can do whatever you want with the `transactions` element.

Comment: It looks like it’s not quite there yet. 1. You’ve got a space and an extra ‘)’ at the end of `driver.FindElement(transactionsTab ));`, which won’t work.  2. When you use `driver.FindElement()` it should be assigned to a variable or appended with `.Click()` otherwise it won’t really do anything.  3. You’re still using `transactions` on the last line without defining it.

Comment: I edited my code, this is not a problem because of this. I/m getting the same error, I can't click on page with protractor driver

Comment: This code resolve my issue:
 
```private const int waitSeconds = 50;```
 ```ngDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);```
 ```ngDriver.IgnoreSynchronization = true;```
 ```ngDriver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitSeconds);```
```ngDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = 
 TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitSeconds);```
```ngDriver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = 
 TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitSeconds);```

Comment: its helped for me

IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;       js.ExecuteAsyncScript("window.setTimeout(arguments[arguments.length - 1], 1000);");

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript click works well on angular where regular `click()` fails: using `C#`,

```
var jsdriver = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

jsdriver?.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```